# How to remove File Filter from file open dialog

Tags: windows-7

How to remove File Filter from file open dialog for win7. I want to make this change at OS level so that if I select open file from any application I dont expect to see file filter dialog.

Answer (score 1):

File Filters are coded into `OpenFileDialog` objects (and its analogues in other development platforms) at Design Time in the program's Development. It's not actually an intrinsic component of Windows and the choice of filter is contained within the relevant program's source, not within a Windows setting.