# How to disable filtering in Windows file chooser dialogs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-chooser

Using Windows (10), it really bugs me that open/save dialogs don't display files that aren't of the selected extension to be opened/saved. I want to see all the files in the folders that I'm looking through; even if I'm not going to select them, they can act like landmarks and help me get my bearings in the filesystem. I like the dialogs in macOS – instead of hiding invalid files, it just grays them out.

Most programs seem to allow you to manually choose "All Files" from that little drop-down to disable this filtering, but it doesn't remember this choice. Is there any way to make this be the default in all programs, or at least in select programs that I use the most? I use AutoHotKey – can any magic be worked with that?

I found this old question ([How to remove File Filter from file open dialog](https://superuser.com/questions/654230/how-to-remove-file-filter-from-file-open-dialog)) which seems to confirm my suspicion that this is baked into applications... Has anything changed since Windows 7?

Thanks!

Comment: No; Nothing has changed